# RedSys - Angular - cryptoJs

Tags: angular7

he intentado implementar el proceso de pago de RedSys en angular tal y como lo tengo en otras web realizadas en .net.
Pero desde el soporte de Redsys lo unico que me dicen es que la firma no es correcta.

Un Saludo y muchas Gracias

```
let objectBack = {
    "DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT": importeTemp,
    "DS_MERCHANT_ORDER": this.correlador,
    "DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE": "175240670",
    "DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY": "978",
    "DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE": "0",
    "DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL": "1",
    "DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL": "www.regalajoyas.com",
    "DS_MERCHANT_URLOK": this.URLOK,
    "DS_MERCHANT_URLKO": this.URLKO
  };


  console.log('1');
  let k = atob(this.moduloAdministracion);
  console.log('2');
  let entidad = btoa(JSON.stringify(objectBack));
  console.log('3');
  let kk = crypto.TripleDES.encrypt(String(this.correlador), k);
  console.log('4', kk);
  let res = crypto.HmacSHA256(entidad, kk);
  console.log('5');
  let result = btoa(res);
  console.log('6');
  this.Ds_MerchantParameters = entidad;
  console.log('7');
  this.Ds_Signature = result;
  console.log('8');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

creo que es porque HmacSHA256 espera un string o un WordArray como llave para hacer el hash. En tu caso, tendrías que cambiar `crypto.HmacSHA256(entidad, kk)` por `crypto.HmacSHA256(entidad, kk.key)` para usar el wordArray o `crypto.HmacSHA256(entidad, kk.ciphertext)` para usarlo como string (a mi me ha servido con el último).

Además, te diría de tener cuidado con el TripleDES, en mi caso me dio bastante problema hasta encontrar que se necesita quitarle el padding (`padding: crypto.pad.ZeroPadding`).

Espero que te sirva de algo.